# What goods would be traded on long distances in post-apocalyptic world?

Tags: post-apocalypse, trade

[Other question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13531/what-would-be-the-development-of-the-most-valuable-irreplaceable-food-trade-goo) concentrate on most valuable goods but most of good listed would involve local trade - for example alcohol can be easily produced with modern knowledge anywhere (see Prohibition in the USA). In similar way the livestock etc. The only things in answers to that question I saw for long-term traded goods would be salt and spices which cannot be produced locally without modern infrastructure.

However I'm more interested with goods which would form a basis for new continental trade networks, like copper and zinc (in the Bronze Age), famous Silk Road and less famous Amber Road (I've seen some speculating about Jet Road being a source of caps being universal currency in *Fallout*).

What goods would start traveling across Europe or across America when society collapses and starts rebuilding at level of city-states (with larger political entity here and there)?

**EDIT** For purpose of this question please consider standard nuclear apocalypse with radiation glowing green and roaming bands of mutants.

**EDIT 2** To clarify I'm looking for good which is a) valuable in such setting and b) decentralized. I don't think that ammunition or guns would be found in much larger quantity in east coast than west coast to make the trade route. On the other hand I don't think black pepper can be easily grown in North Canada.

Comment: Please define your apocalypse. For example if it is zombie apocalypse and somewhere is a huge stash of Z-virus vaccine...

Comment: @Molot differentiation isn't entirely necessary, there are obvious goods that are critical in any disaster scenario: food water power protection

Comment: @anon all 4 you listed make no sense long distance when there is no infrastructure to make it cheaper than moving people once.

Comment: @Molot so you are saying it wouldn't be profitable to transport guns long distances if their community has more than they need?

Comment: @anon what for? And if guns are non renewable, crucial resource, why agree to have less and let someone else have more?

Comment: If I had more guns than I had bullets I would happily trade some guns for bullets while concurrently establishing a good relationship with a bullet provider. Similarily if I could make bullets but I dont have a stable food source perhaps I could sell bullets to a stable farming community without having to put my people in harms way.

Comment: Everything gets traded. Most settlements just aren't going to have everything people want and thus trade is the only way to get it. Things from nonperishable food to clothing to ore to manufactured goods and more can all be moved long distances.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. that's assuming transportation cost is small. In ancient time no one transported grain (non perishable) from Gallia Cisalpina to India as there were cheaper sources of food one the way but local trade between say villages and cities was strong. On the other hand silk and spices were valuable enough to offset the transportation cost.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka You say no one but I would disagree. Traders aren't just going to say "I am only going to trade items X, Y and Z", many people carried food on the trade route and sometimes traded what they had to get other things. Even cheap items are often traded when needed. The whole system is organic in that sense and people traded what they had if they wanted something else.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. Sure but if cost in place A + transport from A + B > cost in place B than the route is unsustainable. Sure, some traders would carry some food while traveling or might cut losses but that would be margins. If item becomes needed in place B than it's price would rise until it reaches A + transport from A + B + epsilon when traders will notice opportunity for arbitrage.

Answer (score 5):

**Information**

Communications will have broken down so wandering minstrels and the like would make a comeback. Communities need to communicate before they can trade, you need to know what I can offer you and what I need before you set off for the long trip to my town.

If it's post-nuke-apoc, then there's plenty of raw materials lying around in the ruined cities, so zinc and copper trading probably wouldn't take off. You'd need to be able to extract and refine it but almost every pre-apoc community would have had a library.

**Services**

So we have knowledge and raw materials. Now my community builds a smithy, and trains a couple of folks to use it. Let's say they make the best ploughshares in the area. Your community wants one but doesn't have the time or resources to train a smith and equip him, so they buy one from me. Supply meets demand, trade results.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on what level of transport infrastructure had been recovered. I suggest that the level of transport available in this world might be usefully matched to the level of transport available during any historical time period to find out what goods might be traded.

It would also depend on the level of government. If there are city states then they should be able to provide protection for trading by supplying troops to protect against bandits and pirates.

**Human only transport**
If the only means of transport is by foot then it would only be practical to transport very high value items with very great difficulty. All food would have to be grown locally. This is a similar situation to that of the ancient Maya.

**Sailing ships plus horses and carts**
Coastal and riverine transport of almost any bulk materials such as stone, leather, pottery, worked metals, cloth and food stuffs are now possible. Away from the coast and rivers horses and cart can be used to transport significant amounts of materials, but food would probably still be grown locally where possible or in locations that are distant from the coast or river network. Materials can be traded over great distances using sea or even river transport, just think of what the Romans were capable of with grain transport from Egypt to Rome.

**Mechanised transport**
If steam power is available then the restriction on moving materials is relaxed further still and even areas distant from the river network and coasts can be reached by train.

Answer (score 2):

### Batteries!

Although you haven't specified a particular apocalypse, since you mention radiation and aliens I'm going to assume this is an "aliens invade and we use nukes to fight them" kind of scenario. In this case, you'll have massive damage done to infrastructure and electrical grids, but you'll still have all the devices that need power to run- laptops, flashlights, water purification devices, etc.

Batteries would be an enormously useful resource because they're semi-rechargeable, portable, and can be used for a huge number of situations. Also, they're already in pretty high demand- that'd only increase during an apocalypse.

Answer (score 2):

**Manufactured goods.**

You can get an idea of what settlers in the wilderness would need by looking at the things salvaged from the sunken steamboat Arabia.  This was a steamboat that sank outside of Kansas City in 1856 and was preserved with its cargo in the deep mud.  It was carrying goods for pioneers in the western territories.

http://1856.com/arabias-story/the-arabia-museum/
[image: the Arabia museum]

I am impressed that nearly everything recovered from the wreck was manufactured goods: ceramic dishes, matches, metalware like forks and knives.  Glassware.  Loads of ax heads.  Huge numbers of shoes and boots.  Textiles.  Also and not really manufactured goods: preserved and pickled fruits.

Manufactured goods have always been trade items.  Manufacturing is a way to add value to a small item.  Manufacturing is centralized and the goods need to travel.  Manufactured goods are usually not perishable.  Textiles were traded at great distances across the ancient world and ever since - silk is the example you read about but Indian cotton has been recovered from ancient tombs in Mongolia.  Porcelain came great distances from China and the same for Roman glassware.  Iron tools were and still are valued trade items - iron plows, knives and axe heads are so much better than wooden or stone tools but you cannot really make your own iron on the farm.

Your places where civilization has come back to some degree would be centers for manufacturing and trade routes would exist to carry materials to outlying areas.  Don't forget your outlying areas need to have something nonperishable and of worth for the traders to bring back: e.g. scavenged relics, furs, whiskey, marijuana, tobacco, slaves.

Answer (score 2):

Books. The ability to distribute information electronically is likely severed by nuclear EMP. So books will be key to rebuilding: physics, engineering, medical, obviously, but also entertainment.

Answer (score 2):

**Salt** 
It can only be gained from salt deposits or from saltwater (assuming that all your local supermarkets have long been looted dry). However, it is very important in a low-tech world for food preservation.

**Animal products**
I'm assuming in your post-apocalyptic world humans have retreated to safe places, which means they probably cannot use open fields to rear animals, or not that many. But nature will survive and localized places will produce different species who survive the apocalypse with the help of certain mutations. It is likely that your humans will hunt them and there will be different animals surviving in different locations. Some will have thick pelts, some will have hard bones which can be carved into implements, some will have other useful parts, like stomachs of ruminants for cheese making, musk glands, horns and hoofs for gelatin, feathers for pillows, and whatever else.

**Geiger-counters** Not many people today would be able to manufacture one, so it is likely that not many will have retained the knowledge in the future, and people who make them won't just give away the secret. Also, they would probably need specific technology from pre-apocalyptic installments, which probably wouldn't be very portable.

Answer (score 1):

The currency of the world in any post apocalypse is commonly known as

"Lead Bullion" aka rounds of ammunition

because in the absence of society and laws he who can enforce his own laws survives.

**EDIT:** apparently it appears there is a common knowledge gap of a popular modern sub-culture.

You should all look into [doomsday preppers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_Preppers).

For obvious reasons I am not going to cover the breadth of knowledge in doomsday prepping. Suffice it to say plenty of people have plans to make bullets in the event of any global disaster precisely because ammunition will be the currency of the land. It's why it's called lead "bullion" lead is a cheap toxic metal otherwise.

Comment: Can you provide any reasoning why this would be the case? As is this looks like a comment not an answer.

Comment: @sphennings its fairly straightforward, if you are in a starving land of lawlessness, bullets can buy you protection, bullets can buy you food, bullets can even buy mates. No other currency will have near the same value. Gold probably wont buy you food neither would diamonds.

Comment: The question asks for trade goods not currency.

Comment: @sphennings its both, a good is something useable and potentially consumable. A currency is merely something that holds fairly universal value. Everyone needs bullets

Comment: 1. Somehow black markets thrive despite being actively hindered by society and laws. Ok, they might not function perfectly but significantly better than 'lead bullion' standard. 2. There exist society in question - world already recovered to have a city states...

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka by that reasoning you are taking the definition of 'post apocalypse' to the period after a global disaster (0 -> infinity) which is meaningless because then trade follows historical trends dependent entirely upon what technologies said civilizations managed to retain or develop. Which means this question should be marked 'too broad'

Comment: I would imagine that in a post apocalypse world that bullets and guns might well be a dieing breed as they are fairly high tech items in a low tech environment (although this is dependant on circumstances). It's not easy to manufacture bullets and even harder to manufacture firearms and gunpowder won't work in modern weapons. Where do the percussion caps come from? who is making nitric and sulphuric acids and how?

Comment: @Slarty guns can be maintained for centuries. Bullets can be made privately. The chemical formula is open knowledge. Plenty of preppers have both the knowledge and equipment to manufacture modern bullets precisely for any of these scenarios. Plus the difficulty is what gives it monetary value in the post-apocalypse

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/40877)

Comment: @L.Dutch OMG Yes it does, ammunition would be a universally tradeable commodity which is why it is favored in the prepper community as a post-apocalyptic currency.

Comment: @anon how do prepers manufacture their gun cartrage propellent and the percussion caps?

Comment: @Slarty Go google prepper sites there are plenty, at the moment I am not in a position where being flagged by DHS is a good thing. Actual homegrown manufacturing methods of bullets is outside scope and is explicitly part of the multitude of prepper knowledge I wasn't going to go into. Which if I must I should flag this question for too broad

Comment: @anon Preppers by definition are interested in local trade. They want to survive immanent end of the world. I'm a) more interested in '200 years later' scenario when parts of knowledge were forgotten on one hand but political entities started to emerge and b) macroeconomic movement of goods. To give an example - average person in middle ages or in antique world did not deal with silk but was interested in more practical matters (food, shelter...). However the trade went on great distance of more special goods. I don't see preppers being interested in that.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Then I vote this closed because that's too broad. By that definition of 'post-apocalyptic' you could describe now as that.

Answer (score 1):

Luxury goods. The immediate concern a after a Apocalypse Is the are necessities (Food water clothing and so on ) Once that's taken care of people began looking for more Usually better clothes better food extra . Through out history  most long distantrade trade has been based around luxury items Silk, Spices, Dyed clothing, Tobacco, Sugar  And so on. I would expect that Once trade slowly starts up again these type of items would again become very valuable and make up most of the transatlantic trade .

Answer (score 0):

Human resources.

Guilds would prosper. Roving craftspeople would go from place to place, like the stone masons of old. I suspect they would primarily be technicians.

Manpower would be at a premium, so I suspect there would be some form of slavery. Employee-employer contracts would be rare, as there would be insufficient resources for payment. If payment is in room and board food only, then that is pretty much servitude. I suspect slaves would not be bought and sold, as in a slave trade, it would be more like mutual dependency ('apprenticeship', for example). The economy would be a return to very early concepts - you sell what you directly produce. Individual entrepreneurial spirit. Individual proprietorship of all business, if you will.

So one of the biggest trade commodities would be in manpower.